# Homegroup Administration

Tags: remote-desktop, administration

At my house there are a number of computers that I would like to remotely administer. For example the following devices are present:

1. Windows 8.1 Professional (64 Bit) Laptop
2. Windows 8.1 Professional (64 Bit) Laptop
3. Windows 10  Professional (64 Bit) Desktop
4. Windows 7   Home Premium (64 Bit) Laptop
5. Windows 7   Ultimate     (64 Bit) Desktop
6. Windows 7   Home Premium (64 Bit) Laptop
7. Windows 7   Home Premium (64 Bit) Laptop

All computers run with the local account (user) being an admin. There is currently no configured domain or homegroup configured. I would like to be able to perform the following on the devices:

```
Remotely install applications and update/uninstall applications. [Choco]
Remotely deploy printers using a created batch script.
Remotely execute de fragments, anti-virus scan and windows updates.
Remotely execute backups to network drives.
Configure GP via one centralised point, or simply bulk edit the local PC.
```

For security reasons, I do not want to prevent them from doing these tasks themselves, I just want to be able to remotely perform these tasks when needed. It may sound lazy, but I want to be able to remotely execute a local backup of the computers simultaneously without needing to manually disturb the users.

Furthermore, each PC/User have a different anti-virus program; I have Bit Defender Total Security on the Windows 8, ESET NOD32 on all Windows 7 except Ultimate, and Kaspersky Total Security on the Windows 7 Ultimate. Administering scans and changes to the settings here could be a problem.

I want to set this up in the most secure manner, preferably without needing to purchase any enterprise software. Would I need to configure some administrator account locally on each computer, then utilise some freeware tool to run programs?

There is a free tool called "Remote Utilities" which uses NT permissions to remotely install, reboot etc. computers. Something along these lines would be preferable.

I am not so much asking for software recommendations, more the safest and most effective way to implement this.

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser. but personally I would go the Domain route, it would take one desktop to set up but will give you everything else you want, but you can't connect Home Premium Machines to it.

Comment: All those OS's have automatic scheduled defrag. Maintaining 7 windows PC's is a part time job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I used largely incorporated [PS Exec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) as the method:

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
```

Identifying the PC via it's *static* IP address. With PS Exec I specified the *local* administrative account and remotely setup task schedules for backups (using `robocopy` and `7z` command line)

I was able to deploy printers remotely with [PrintBM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134237(v=ws.11).aspx) and as all PC's have the same printer, any changes on my PC I could relay (again relying on PS Exec).

Remote Scans proved to be too much to schedule from my PC, so I just task scheduled this within the actual application to allow it to auto-run. The same for disk defragmentation etc.